# Can debuggers modify registers

Tags: c, debugging, language-agnostic

### Base

Given a simple multiple choice question:

Debugger is a program that

> A. Allows to examine and modify the contents of registers
>
> B. Allows to set breakpoints, execute a segment of program and
> display contents of register
>
> C. Does not allow execution of a segment of program
>
> D. All the options

My basic understanding of programming says:

1. If it is a native code debugger `All the options` are correct.
2. In case of interpreted or virtual machine based language `non of the options` are correct as registers are not dealt directly in these languages. This renders the question incorrect thus we can conclude the type of debugger asked in question is probably some low level native code debugger.

### Background

This question was asked in one scientific recruitment exam of India. The official answer key by the country's apex computer science organization mentioned `Option B` as correct answer. This questions my whole understanding of subject and I couldn't figure out how a debugger can allow viewing a common register (except for protected cpu registers like `cr` series, gdtr etc in x86) but not modifying it except intentionally restricted in a debugger program.

### Question

I know the question is somewhat conflicting and unclear but if one point has to be agreed upon, what could it be?

### My Attempt

To find a solution I wrote a C program and ran it against gdb.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int perform_sum(int x, int y){
  return x+y;
}

void skip_scaler_func(int *base, int scale){
  int count;
  for (count = 2; count <= scale; ++count)
  {
    *base += count;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 1 ;
  int result_sum = 16, result_skip = 55;

  // modify the return register value i.e eax(x86) or rax(x86_64)
  int calculated_sum = 1 + perform_sum(10, 5);

  // try to skip the next function call i.e. a segment of code
  skip_scaler_func(&i, 10);

  PRINT_ROUTINES: 

  if(calculated_sum == result_sum){
    printf("- Actual sum matches, no registers modified\n");
  }else {
    printf("+ Actual sum was %d, Got result as %d, debugger modified register\n", result_sum, calculated_sum);
  }

  if(i == result_skip){
    printf("- Actual scaling matches, no program segment skipped\n");
  }else {
    printf("+ Actual scaling was %d, Got result as %d, debugger skipped skip_scaler_func\n", result_skip, i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

while the gdb script was:

```
set pagination off
set logging file gdb.output
set logging on

# We will break on perform_sum, then finish and modify register eax
break perform_sum
# Will break on line 25 and skip the whole block
break 25
run
finish
# Change the return result of 15 to 20 by modifying accumulator.
set $eax=20
cont
# Now skip
jump PRINT_ROUTINES

set logging off
quit
```

Compilation:

```sh
# Compile the code for x86_64
gcc -g -m64 102.c -o 102
# Run the code
./102
# Output:
#> - Actual sum matches, no debugger modification
#> - Actual scaling matches, no debugger modification

# Now run inside gdb, result in next section
gdb --command=102.gdb --args ./102
```

Output:

```
Reading symbols from ./102...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400587: file 102.c, line 5.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4005fd: file 102.c, line 25.

Breakpoint 1, perform_sum (x=10, y=5) at 102.c:5
5         return x+y;
0x00000000004005f7 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd6b8) at 102.c:22
22        int calculated_sum = 1 + perform_sum(10, 5);
Value returned is $1 = 15

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd6b8) at 102.c:25
25        skip_scaler_func(&i, 10);


+ Actual sum was 16, Got result as 21, debugger modified register
+ Actual scaling was 55, Got result as 1, debugger skipped skip_scaler_func


[Inferior 1 (process 17988) exited normally]
```

### Conclusion

The script also indicates possibility of all options.

Comment: I'm not aware of any machine-code debugger that *doesn't* let you set register values.

Comment: A low level debugger would be able to modify anything on any virtual layer on top of the native architecture too. Sure, `gdb` running inside virtual machine won't be able to see anything on the host.

Comment: Yes of course, taking ideal case for academic purpose we don't even need to go till virtual layer, every proof is against official answer.

Comment: If I take a formalistic approach "B: allows to execute a segment of program" && "C: Does not allow execution of a segment of program" => B and C are in conflict, "All of the above" is not a great choice. (the whole question is bad, I agree)

Comment: Also A and C are in conflict, if you can modify registers, you can execute a part of the program.

Comment: @dratenik Conditionally it can allow both, thus a union will always be both true :P

Comment: I'd say A and B, but not C.  It is not even clear what C means, but the whole purpose of the debugger is to execute the program - in whole or part.  It may not make much sense to set the program counter arbitrarily into any part of the program, but the debugger won't stop you.  I do it all the time to repeat a section of code with different values.  If you had to choose 1, then (B) since that is probably true regardless of language, compiled, interpreted or virtual..

Comment: @Clifford Theoretically a debugger can fill an arbitrary memory location with arbitrary code and jump there to execute it. So I'd agree - C is not correct.

Comment: @Clifford interpreted languages never show registers even if they do so it will be completely irrelevant so I don't know if there is any practical debugger which has took headache of implementing it. Since you have used A often, I have used C often in reverse engineering when I .. can't say .. but you understand skipping some sections :D

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I got your point and cliffords too. Probably you mean restricting execution. That is also ambiguous in question!!! It might mean skipping a part of code (As I was thinking) or completely restricting a part of code.

Comment: Bottom line - the question is not correct, which happens sometimes with interview questions, and the proposed answer B is not (the only) correct. The correct ones are A and B. But, unlike exams, on interview you can argue about this and prove your point. For example by referring to `gdb` command `set`, like in `set $sp+=8`

Comment: @Avezan agreed - the bit about displaying registers required a sideways scroll - I assumed it was _variables_ or _memory_.  It is not clear why you used code mark-up for the question - it would have line wrapped otherwise.  I doubt you have used C - says says you _cannot_ execute code in a debugger (any code) it is clearly nonsense.